# Getting error - .........either make it static or add a no-args constructor to your class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, rest-assured

I am writing test scripts with Rest-Assured java. I have two classes ApiMethods and AppMethods belonging to one package and another test package called apiTests using the methods created in the ApiMethods and AppMethods classes. I am getting error (Can't invoke public void apiTests.TestCase.caseApi(): either make it static or add a no-args constructor to your class) while running the test class file.

AppMethods class looks like this:

```
package com.sape.utilMethods;

import com.sape.base.Base;

public class AppMethods extends Base{
    
    private String MethodA(String abc) {
      //Some code
      //return statement 

    }
}
```

ApiMethods class looks like this:

```
package com.sape.utilMethods;

import com.sape.base.Base;

public class ApiMethods extends Base{
    
    public AppMethods appObj;

    public ApiMethods(AppMethods appObj) {
        this.appObj = appObj;
    }

    public String MethodB() {
       appObj.MethodA();
    }
}
```

The test case class under apiTests package looks like this:

```
package apiTests;

import com.sape.base.Base;
import com.sape.utilMethods.ApiMethods;
import com.sape.utilMethods.AppMethods;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

public class TestCase extends Base {
        
    public AppMethods appObj;
    public ApiMethods apiMethods;
    
    public TestClass(AppMethods appObj) {
        this.appObj = appObj;
        this.apiMethods= new ApiMethods(appObj);
    }

    @Test
    public void caseApi() {
        
        apiMethods.MethodB();
        
        
    }
}
```

It seems I am doing something incorrectly in the caseApi method, while creating ApiMethods object. Can someone help me in passing the data correctly? I am bit new to java so sorry if this question is something very basic

Comment: Your error message mentions `TestCase` class. Where is it?

Comment: Corrected the question

Answer (score 2):

Why you are initializing the `AppMethods` `ApiMethods` inside the testclass constrcutor this is not right way **testng** works only with the class which has constructor with no arguments

You can use `@BeforeTest` for intilizing the classes so that your `testclass.java` will be as shown below

```
public class TestClass extends Base {
        
    public AppMethods appObj;
    public ApiMethods apiMethods;
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void start(){
        appObj =new AppMethods();
        apiMethods= new ApiMethods(appObj);
    }

    @Test
    public void caseApi() {
        apiMethods.MethodB();           
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Specifically, a `class` only has a no-arg constructor if 1) it specifically declares it, such as `public TestCase() { /* .... /* }` or 2) it has no other constructor. Mohamed's solution opts for the second, which is arguably the simplest way in vanilla Java.